# Receipt roll paper like layout android

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

How can I design my layout where the borders are zigzag styled like it was ripped from the printing roll of receipt paper.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how you done it?

Comment: Well I had to design such layout with photoshop.

Comment: even me too... :)